# How to go to another network or host in Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, command-line, ms-dos

Example, I have network 3 host namely RJMB , SOBRANG , GWAPO
currently I am in the host RJ..
What is the specific command to go to another host?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “go to”? Browsing other PCs’ file shares? Connecting using SSH or the like?

Comment: @DanielB Hello Daniel like I am changing my workspace. Because right now I am currently doing some stuffs at specific directory in hostname RJ . . Since I am done, I need to go to a specific directory which can be found at hostname "Sobrang" . . So I don't know how . . Since each hostname has different IP address, do you think it would also help? really have no idea :(

Answer (score 1):

If by 'go to another network' you mean, change the directory to \\sobrang\some\path, that is not possible directly.

What you need to do is map the shared network path to a drive letter. After you've done that you can 'go to' that drive.

Suppose you are working on RJMB, and you want to go to a directory on SOBRANG:

```
:: Map the path to Z:
net use Z: \\sobrang\some

:: Open a folder
cd /D Z:\path
```

The `net use` command maps a remote path (\sobrang...) to a drive on the computer you are working on. You will get an extra drive letter (Z: in this example) that you can use just as any other drive (C: D: etc). The drive letter you specify in net use should not be in use yet.

If you want to disconnect the drive you just mapped, use

```
net use Z: /delete
```

(Make sure you CD out of Z: first)

Comment: Hey @Berend , Thank you for your response and excuse me for being slow on this. I'd like to clarify that "map" thing . .Here is my understanding of what you said,
Example, I am working in computer or network "RJMB" and I like to change my directory found in another network "Sobrang" . What I need to do is to execute a command inside a specific drive in "RJMB" that will map or connect "Sobrang". I'm sorry , I'm lost.

Comment: Exactly. The `net use` command maps a remote path (\\sobrang\...) to a drive on the computer you are working on. You will get an extra drive letter that you can use just as any other drive (C: D: etc). The drive letter you specify in net use should not be in use yet.